# setting constant number of columns & weird collectionView width

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to set a number of columns in collection view to always be 3, regardless of device.
I'm using this code in viewDidLoad method:

```
let width = CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame)/3.0
        let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical

        print("width:\(width),   collectionViewWidth:\(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView!.frame)),   mainViewWidth:\(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame))")
```

I always get only 1 column. The print method return some useful debugging information. They state the following:

width:186.666666666667,
 collectionViewWidth:560.0,
 mainViewWidth:320.0

What is going on? How is the collectionViewWidth bigger than main's? What is the correct way of setting a constant number of columns? I specified the size of collectionView using constraints in Interface Builder and it should be less than mainView's.

Comment: I think you make a view with `hAny wAny`....and make 20 pixel space from both left and right side.....you should write this code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes, I'm using autolayout. shipping this code to viewWillLayoutSubviews did the trick

Comment: It looks like, that putting my code in viewWillLayoutSubviews is not a good solution. whenever I rotate my device to landscape and than return to portrait, the wrong size gets evaluated and my column number is back to 1. Any suggestions?